# joomla 2.5 view only image intro for any preview category

Tags: php, image, joomla

i have a problem with file override "blog_item.php".
I want to see only the first image in each category without the introductory text. how can I do?
I wrote this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($images->image_intro) and !empty($images->image_intro))
{
    $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_intro)) ? $params->get('float_intro') : $images->float_intro;
    $class = (htmlspecialchars($imgfloat) != 'none') ? ' class="size-auto align-'.htmlspecialchars($imgfloat).'"' : ' class="size-auto"';
    $title = ($images->image_intro_caption) ? ' title="'.htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption).'"' : '';
    echo '<img'.$class.$title.' src="'.htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro).'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt).'" />';
}?>

<?php echo $this->$images->image_intro; ?>
```

Comment: What do you see? Are there any errors? I did notice that you don't have `$this->images->...` everywhere in the code, only in the last statement.

Comment: Or you can try var_dump($this->images) to see what happend? One more thing, I see that in the last statement which is wrong. images without $

Answer (score 0):

I think Joomla is not using your file. You can verify this by adding something very visible to the file, such as

```
<h1>YOU'RE HERE</h1>
```

if you don't see the new text after clearing the cache continue reading.

1. Make sure you have placed blog_item in the right folder (templates/your_template/html/com_content/category/)
2. Also, all the files from /components/com_content/views/category/tmpl need to be copied to your override, not just blog_item.php

If this doesn't solve it, it's definitely a sourcery